# How to get database contents from my website to local machine

Tags: mysql, ftp, web

I have ftp access but would like to see content of mysql.

Basically myy website got hacked and the contents of my site is saved to mysql, how can I retrieve the content of database?

Where would the files be? The website was made by someone else so this will be first time I will be logging in via ftp.

I hope above makes sense. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on widnows or linux ? File location depends on the OS you use.

Comment: Can't you access the mysql server that holds/manages/serves your mysql? Did you consider contacting your hosting provider rather than asking on a programming Q/A Website? And how is this a php question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To get the access of database you need to contact to you hosting
>   company and ask for database access . If possible ask them to provide
>   you the access of phpmyadmin. Then you will be able to access the
>   database.
>
> Even if you do not find contents on MYSQL database . Try this link
>   http://archive.org/web/ and try to find the the most recent copy of
>   your web pages. At least you will be able to get the original contents
>   and structure of you site.

I hope it helps